# How to force a linked library to load using Visual C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, global-variables, libraries

I am trying to handle a project with multiple dynamic libraries, in the libraries some global objects are created and registered in a list so that the executable can use them to build other things. In the executable there's no reference to any function of any library, it just needs the objects, and then it knows what to do. These libraries are intended to work like plugins that are chosen at link time.

Ideally when compiling `ExecutableProject` I link `LibraryA`, an object of type `A` gets created (by some code that's compiled in the library) and `ExecutableProject` does things because of it, using functions in `LibraryA`. If instead I link `LibraryB` then an object of type `B` gets created and other things happen.

The problem is, since ExecutableProject does not directly use any function or class in the library, the library is not loaded, and objects are never created.

I have found some workarounds:

1. I can use `/INCLUDE:symbol` at link time when compiling `ExecutableProject`, where symbol is any symbol exported in `LibraryA` or `LibraryB`. I don't like this because I have to know the decorated name of a function in the library, which is not always available. Also, it's not elegant.
2. I can use a dummy variable. I could put `__declspec(dllexport) int force_link_A_or_B;` in `LibraryA` and `LibraryB` and `__declspec(dllimport) extern int force_link_A_or_B;` in `ExecutableProject`. I don't like this because if I had more libraries I'd have to add a variable for each of them. Basically although the code in `ExecutableProject` does not know which libraries will be linked, it still needs to know how many of them can be linked together.

On Linux, using gcc and ld, it's very easy to solve this problem, all it takes is a simple linker flag `-Wl,--no-as-needed`. Is there any way to do this using Visual Studio? I would be happy if there was something that worked like `/INCLUDE` but used entire libraries instead of symbols and did not need decorated names.

Thanks

EDIT: I have been asked to clarify how this design is intended to work.  Ideally, when I compile `ExecutableProject` I link `LibraryA` or `B` and an object is created.

```
`ClassA A;`
```

This is placed outside all functions in a source file that is compiled in `LibraryA`. Same thing happens in `LibraryB`. The key here is that `ClassA` and `ClassB` inherit from a `BaseClass` that `ExecutableProject` knows well. When the object is created, the `BaseClass` constructor is run, and inside it a `BaseClass*` pointer pointing to `this` (therefore the derived object) is saved, and `ExecutableProject` uses that pointer. It does not need to know anything about the derived classes, because it uses only a `BaseClass` pointer, but when it calls virtual functions from it, different functions are executed depending on the actual type of the pointed object. If there were more objects instead that just two alternatives, I would save `BaseClass` pointers in a list or a map, and let `ExecutableProject` access it.

Comment: Do you really need a reference to your DLL to be added to the executable during compilation? This is very unusual.

Comment: Your question appears self-contradicting. On one hand, "In the executable there's no reference to any function of any library". On the other, "and ExecutableProject does things because of it, using functions in LibraryA." So do you, or do you not, use functions from the library? And if you don't, then what's the purpose of the library? Can you show some code demonstrating your setup? It makes little sense to me.

Comment: `I don't like this because I have to know the decorated name of a function in the library` Use .def file to export a symbol with plain, undecorated name.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee apparently the linker ignores "unused" libraries.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ExecutableProject knows what to do because some static objects are created in the libraries and registered in a map. I will update the question with clarification.

Comment: I'd just export a function, say `BaseClass* GetObject()`, from each library, and have the executable call it. Or, just skip the process of reinventing the wheel, and make those DLLs COM servers (where [`DllGetClassObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680760.aspx) exported function plays this role).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try this. The design is fundamentally flawed.

In particular, since you are not making any explicit calls to the DLL, you would rely only on object `A` being created via an implicit call to `DllMain`.

But under Windows rules, you are barred from doing anything interesting in or from `DllMain`, so object `A` cannot be very useful.

Comment: thank you. Can you please clarify more your message? I agree that this design is overly complicated, but I think it could work. Please check my edit to my question, which further explains how the project works. What really matters is that `A` exists.

Comment: I have same problem but my case is different: I link exe file against dll which injects things to global objects from exe file (I use Qt framework and I use qApp global instance to alter some things). And because dll file is not loaded due to being "not used", I do not get what I need.